# Why I can use only private key to login a server using ssh?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I generated the keypair in Computer 1.

And move the public key to the Computer2(server) and make it in authorized_keys.

And move the private key to Computer3(client) and use `ssh-add` to add it.

Why I can directly login to server without offering a public key? What's the real workflow of ssh key authorization?

Comment: Your public key has been on the server already, it's used to authenticate that you do own the corresponding private key. You may want to learn the basic concept of asymmetrical encryption.

Comment: A fun read for those who want to understand RSA: https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/txt/rsa.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The client (Computer 3) does have access to the public key

You are perhaps confusing a private key **file** with a private key.

When you generate a public/private key pair, most implementations will create a private key file which contains BOTH the private and public key.
Many implementations also write public key to a file separately for convenience.

According [RFC 4252 Section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252#section-7) the public key is supplied by the client during authentication.  Therefore your client MUST have it available.

With openssh's `ssh-keygen` you can extract the public key from your private key file:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

---

## The authentication mechanism

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252#section-7

Before the client tries to login, it *may* first check to see what would be acceptable.  This check can include sending public keys matching its available private keys and thus allows the server to indicate which public/private key to use.

> ... the signing operation involves some expensive computation.  To
> avoid unnecessary processing and user interaction, the following
> message is provided for querying whether authentication using the
> "publickey" method would be acceptable.
>
> ```
>   byte      SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST
>   string    user name in ISO-10646 UTF-8 encoding [RFC3629]
>   string    service name in US-ASCII
>   string    "publickey"
>   boolean   FALSE
>   string    public key algorithm name
>   string    public key blob
> ```

Then it attempts to login

> To perform actual authentication, the client MAY then send a
> signature generated using the private key.  The client MAY send the
> signature directly without first verifying whether the key is
> acceptable.  The signature is sent using the following packet:
>
> ```
>   byte      SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST
>   string    user name
>   string    service name
>   string    "publickey"
>   boolean   TRUE
>   string    public key algorithm name
>   string    public key to be used for authentication
>   string    signature
> ```

Notice that this includes both the public key and a signature generated with the private key.  The public key is helpful to the server SSH where it has many "authorized keys"; the server doesn't have to test the signature against each one.

Unlike some similar algorithms, SSH doesn't use a challenge-response.  That is it **doesn't** use a four step (1 client initiate, 2 server challenge, 3 client sign, 4 server verifies) it performs a two step:

1. Client signs the [session identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252#section-1) (Ie: a hash produced by the earlier [DH Key Exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-8))
2. The server then verifies that:

   - The the specified public key is acceptable (in the user's authorized keys)
   - Decrypting the signature with the specified public key, produces the session identifier

---

## Why are some people confused about this?

The technique of public / private key authentication doesn't need the client to hold the public key.  The client just needs to write a signature with the private key.  The server just needs to check the signature with the matching public key.

However SSH allows a client to have many private keys and the server to have many authorized keys for a user.  If a client had 10 keys and the server accepted 10 keys but only one pair of them matched, the client would have to send 10 signatures and the server would have to check each against 10 keys (100 checks in all).  This is computationally expensive.  SSH instead can handle the same situation with just a single signature check.

Answer (score 5):

Your public key is only used to verify the private key is valid.

When you ssh from the local machine and you point to the private key for authentication, the remote machine creates a challenge.  Your local machine then sends the challenge back using your private key to encrypt it.  The server will then decrypt the message using your public key and as long as the challenge is valid it will allow connection.
**You should never share your private key**

[image]

Comment: But in [rfc4252](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4252) there is no random data sent to client and client should sign a signature with specific public key.

Comment: "An authentication request MAY result in a further exchange of
   messages."

Comment: "With this method, the possession of a private key serves as
   authentication.  This method works by sending a signature created
   with a private key of the user.  The server MUST check that the key
   is a valid authenticator for the user, and MUST check that the
   signature is valid.  If both hold, the authentication request MUST be
   accepted; otherwise, it MUST be rejected.  Note that the server MAY
   require additional authentications after successful authentication."

Comment: Where does it say the **client** should sign with a **public key**?

Comment: "This method works by having the client send a signature created with
   the **private key** of the client host, which the server checks with that
   host's **public key**."

Comment: @Jesse_b From what I can read in the standard, the client sends the signature in a packet that also contains the public key.  This presumably to prevent the server having to try it against every key in a user's authorized keys.  It also has an optional prior check to see if the server accept the public key before it generates a signature with the matching private key.#

Comment: This answer is wrong on many points. The public key **is** sent by the client during authentication.  The remote machine does **not** create a challenge.  The client does **not** encrypt a random message from the server, it encrypts the [session identifier](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4252#section-1) ([and here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4252#section-1))  created by an earlier [DH Key exchange](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253#section-8) which combines random data from both server and client.  The diagram is also wrong.

Comment: @Anon see my previous comment. You are half correct.  Random data is signed, but it's produced in an earlier step (not part of authentication).