# Does ssh client need public key, also?

Tags: debian, openssh

My understanding is that openssh client requires only private key, the corresponding public key must be in the Server. However, I see the following in the ssh client when I increase the verbosity level to 3.

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:VvQDLGFJdfO9FUOqa1ODV6iLT4Te0Nm5Bz1OUA57LjY
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:VvQDLGFJdfO9FUOqa1ODV6iLT4Te0Nm5Bz1OUA57Lj
```

What does it mean when it says - "`Next authentication method: public key`" ?
Why is it using public key?

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/515922/4778

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the term "public key authentication" is a generic term used for authentication using asymmetric key cryptography using a public/private key pair.

Secondly, the public key *is* sent to the server as part of the ssh authentication process. The client sends a packet containing (among other things) the public key; this packet is encrypted using the corresponding private key. This packet identifies the user, and the signature, if the server can verify it, authenticates the user.

The server checks that the public key is present on the server. The role of the `authorized_keys` file, as the name says, is an *authorization* mechanism as opposed to an *authentication* mechanism. I.e. the presence of a key in the `authorized_keys` *authorizes* the user to use a certain key, so not just any public key is accepted by the server. Note that a user can have more than one key in the `authorized_keys` file.

Answer (score 2):

The public key can be derived (Where derived may in this case mean stored with) from the private key.
The private key is private, **must not be shared**.

Therefore in the early steps of connecting, when trying to work out what key to use. It will probably wave some public keys at the server. If there is a match then the server will ask it to prove that it has the private key.

Comment: Could you elaborate on it wave some public keys at the server? What are those public keys? The client doesn't have public key then what is it waving.

Comment: See first sentence, for where the public key comes from.

Comment: An RSA public key can *usually* be derived from the private key. This is because the public exponent `e` is normally quite small, but it doesn't have to be small. Deriving the public key like this is not something that is normally done. The public and private keys are generated as a pair, and both keys are kept, i.e. you don't throw away the public key.